# How to scroll div with another div?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic project, in which there is a list of items in ion-content:

```
<ion-content padding #myContent>
       <!-- lots of data -->
</ion-content>
```

Ion-footer has a next button executing tasks on click.

```
<ion-footer>
  <div *ngIf="nextButtonHolder">
    <div *ngIf="nextButton" class="next" (click)="next()">
</div>
</div>
</ion-footer>
```

Class next is a fixed div overlapping the content

```
.next{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 10; //overlapping content
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

How can I bind the "next" overlapping div (apart from being clickable with function next()) to scroll the ion-content, without assigning next() to ion-content itself?

Answer (score 1):

Element.prototype.scoll(x: number, y: number). Can't it help?

Comment: Could you please clarify by providing an example for the above problem with your solution?